# get list of all tasks in Angular

Tags: angular, loops, filter, mapping

I got a list of task and subtask array where I need to iterate through all the `tasks` and display the data. But I'm only getting the data of only the first set of subtasks of `tasks`. For example from the below data I'm only getting main task 1 and it's subtasks, but after that, it's not iterating through the second set of `task` i.e Main task 2 and it's subtasks.

```
"tasks":[{"task":"main task 1","status":"pending","subtask":["subtask1","SubTask:2","SubTask:3","SubTask:4"],"_id":"5f75a789c58225229cddf077"},{"task":"Main task 2","status":"pending","subtask":["SubTask:1","SubTask:4"],"_id":"5f75a789c58225229cddf078"}]
```

```
    let i = 1
    tasks.map(x => {

      this[`subtask${i}`] = x.task

      x.subtask.filter(y => {
        for (let j = 1; j <= 5; j++) {

          this[`detail${i - 1}${j}`] = x.subtask[j - 1]

        }

      });

      i++

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it's will help you :

```
items = [
    {"task":"main task 1","status":"pending","subtask":["subtask1","SubTask:2","SubTask:3","SubTask:4"],"_id":"5f75a789c58225229cddf077"},
    {"task":"Main task 2","status":"pending","subtask":["SubTask:1","SubTask:4"],"_id":"5f75a789c58225229cddf078"}
];

mapped = this.items.map(item => {
    console.log(item.task)
    console.log(item.subtask)
});
```